# Can you rely on the order of Android Room Ids returned from a multi row insert

Tags: android, android-room

Im using Room for my local database within my current Android application.

I have a One-to-Many parent child table relationship where I would like to insert Multiple Parent rows, receive the auto generated ids back as a List then insert multiple children per parent Id.

Can I rely that Room returns the auto generated parent Ids in the same order as the parent rows I passed to the INSERT statement?

I receive 200 parent rows at a time, which means I do not want to have to insert individual parent rows as this approach will degrade performance.

Is there any method where I can insert multiple Parent -> Children one-2-many rows and have the children rows automatically receive the parent auto generated id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any method where I can insert multiple Parent -> Children one-2-many rows and have the children rows automatically receive the parent auto generated id?

I doubt such a method exists. Though you could consider next workaround (of course it has some drawbacks but you could think if it's suitable in your specific case) - before insert to get maximal `id` and set `id`s in your `Parent` and `Child` entities explicitly. Let's say you have 200 items to insert. You get maximal current `id` - 1000. Then you set `id`'s in your first Parent/Child pair - 1001, in second - 1002 and so on. With that you can insert Parent and Child lists within single `Insert`.

> Can I rely that Room returns the auto generated parent Ids in the same order as the parent rows I passed to the INSERT statement?

You can. Just look at Room's method `insertAndReturnIdsList`, that is called when you insert List of entities:

```
// THIS METHOD IS CALLED WITHIN TRANSACTION WHEN YOU CALL YOUR INSERT-DAO-METHOD
public final List<Long> insertAndReturnIdsList(Collection<? extends T> entities) {
        final SupportSQLiteStatement stmt = acquire();
        try {
            final List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>(entities.size());
            int index = 0;
            for (T entity : entities) { <-- LOOPING LIST OF INSERTED ENTITIES
                bind(stmt, entity);
                result.add(index, stmt.executeInsert()); <-- INSERT ONE-BY-ONE IN ONE TRANSACTION
                index++; <-- INDEX OF RESULT LIST MATCHES INDEX OF ENTITIES LIST
            }
            return result;
        } finally {
            release(stmt);
        }
    }
```